# Contextual closure type '() -> Text' expects 0 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this Swift code here:

```swift
struct chapter: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ForEach(1..<18) { _ in
                NavigationLink(destination: chapterrun()) {
                    Text("Chapter \($0)")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("App")
    }
}
```

But it gives the error:

`Contextual closure type '() -> Text' expects 0 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body`

How do I fix this?

Comment: You are using `$0` in a closure that has no parameters. I think you wanted to use the value from the `ForEach`, but you used `_` there...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two closures, so $0 from first one (even if it would be correct, but with `_ in` you just ignore it) is not available in second one.

The fix is to use argument explicitly, like

```
ForEach(1..<18) { index in   // << here !!
    NavigationLink(destination: chapterrun()) {
        Text("Chapter \(index)")  // << here !!
    }
}
```